# equals() generated by Eclipse: getOuterType()?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have simple class Point with two fields of type `double`. I asked Eclipse 3.6 to generate `equals()` and `hashCode()` for it. The `equals()` method looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Point other = (Point) obj;
    if (!getOuterType().equals(other.getOuterType()))
        return false;
    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(x) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.x))
        return false;
    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(y) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.y))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

And the `getOuterType` looks like this:

```
private Point getOuterType() {
    return Point.this;
}
```

So the question is: what's the purpose of `getOuterType().equals(other.getOuterType())` line?

Comment: It turns out that I have, thanks, it's solved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, if your class is an inner class (non-static nested class), it has an outer, enclosing instance. Two objects of an inner class type aren't really equal unless the enclosing instances are equal, too; the outer instance like a hidden field (usually named `this$0` by `javac`).

Comment: Eclipse seems to think it is an inner class. Otherwise it would not be generating a `getOuterType` method.

Comment: Thanks, Chris! The question actually came from my student, it seems that he really put his class inside some other. (I can't reproduce this on my computer until put the class inside other after your answer.)

Comment: I've wondered the same thing.  Previous to this check of the OuterType, the code checks that the classes of both entities are the same.  If you know the classes are the same, why bother checking the outer type?  Isn't that redundant?  You KNOW the outer type is the same because the 'inner' type is the same.

Comment: @ticktock The outer _types_ are the same, but the outer _instances_ (which is what the `getOuterType` returns) are not necessarily the same. That's what the comparison is for.

Comment: Ah.. there we go.  So getOuterType() is a really poor choice of naming.  It should be 'getOuterInstance()' or some such.  Thanks Chris.

Comment: waking up this old thread.. Shouldn't it be getOuterType().equals(this) ? because equals should compare equality, not identity

Comment: I've submitted a bug report to get the naming of getOuterType fixed: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=539872